# Installing topGO package in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I try to install the topGO package as the cmd in the [webpage](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/topGO.html):

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("topGO")
```

But there are some errors as below:

> Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
>   call: sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data)
>   error: RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: disk I/O error)
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed

Then i want to install GO.db package in R as the instruction on the webpage

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("GO.db")
```

and i counter the same problem as i posted above:

> Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘sort’
>   Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘rank’
>   Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘as.data.frame’
>   Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘unlist’
>   Warning: multiple methods tables found for ‘match’
>   Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
>   call: sqliteExecStatement(con, statement, bind.data)
>   error: RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: database is locked)
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed

This is the output after i typed sessionInfo() on R:

> R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16) Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>   (64-bit)
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [3] LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8      [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8     [7] LC_PAPER=C 
>   LC_NAME=C                   [9] LC_ADDRESS=C
>   LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8
>   LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  methods   [8] base
>
> other attached packages: [1] AnnotationDbi_1.22.6 Biobase_2.20.1
>   BiocGenerics_0.6.0   [4] BiocInstaller_1.10.3
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] DBI_0.2-7
>   IRanges_1.18.3 RSQLite_0.11.4 stats4_3.0.1   tools_3.0.1

I think there is a problem about installing GO.db package.
Any advice is appreciate!
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioconductor/2010-June/034240.html) is helpful?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This thread really help me solve the problem. Thanks